# Calculating the pixel variance of a mask in an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I trying to analyze statistically an eye image. I have an elipse that covers the whole eye area.

This is my original image:

[image]

This is the mask generated in form of ellipse:

[image]

I found this [link](https://www.nbshare.io/notebook/160784578/How-To-Handle-nan-In-Numpy/) that suggests the calculation of covariance but i cant really grasp how to work with ma module of numpy, and its not quite variance. https://www.nbshare.io/notebook/160784578/How-To-Handle-nan-In-Numpy/

Here's my current code from what i was trying:

```
img = 'path'
img = Image.fromarray(img)
img_PIL = img

    h_1 = 13
    k_1 = 23.5
    a_1 = 3
    b_1 = 5
    
   def _in_ellipse_sub_mask(x, y, h, k, a, b):
        z = ((x-h)**2)/a**2 + ((y-k)**2)/b**2
        if z < 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    in_ellipse_mask = np.vectorize(_in_ellipse_iris)
    img = np.asarray(img)
    
    mask_ = _in_ellipse_sub_mask(*np.indices(img.shape), h_1,k_1,a_1,b_1)
    
    plt.imshow(mask_ )
    plt.show()

mask_var = np.nanvar(np.where(sub_mask_, img, np.nan), dtype=np.float64, out=None, ddof=1)
```

The output:

> 0.04677148697358601

I was expecting a large number over 100, but i guess this isnt the right way to calculate variance for masks, given that masks works with boolean values, it will not give me a proper result

Comment: ["Covariance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) usually involves two random variable being compared. What two things do you want to compute covariance between? A matrix of covariances between every pair of pixels in the eye? Or do you just want the scalar *variance* over the eye?

Comment: I do not want covariance, but just the variance, the link gives me something really close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `img` is a matrix with values between 0 to 1 (indicating grayscale levels). You expect the values to be 0-255. This is why you expect variance to be more than 100. So multiply the `img` values by 255 before the `nanvar()` or just the result by 255^2 (scaling property). Please note that `nanvar()` flattens matrix to vector before performing calculations, this is how you can get a scalar out of the matrix.

As for `ma` submodule, masked array contains two parts: `data` and `mask`. `data` is the actual data array, `mask` is a boolean matrix of the same dimensions as `data` with 1 in the places you want to disregard (mask) and 0 in the  places you care (the unmasked values). The `ma` math functions ignore masked values.